# Any recommendation for a Dark Heresy character generator/manager?

Tags: tools, dark-heresy-1e, tool-recommendation

We run a post apocalyptic "Fallout" style campaign in Dark Heresy with some friends. After a while situations like characters got lost or chewed by my dog, led us wondering if there is any Character generator / manager for Dark Heresy as a mobile app or something similar.

We are not looking for a full campaign manager or a website, like Roll20, just for an app that holds characters.

Any suggestions?

P.S. In case there is no proper solution, we were looking at making our own mobile app with a friend. Doing it so probably gets tricky with copyrights etc and I don't know if it's feasible.

Comment: "We are not looking for a full campaign manager or a website, like Roll20" -- Although I would point out that Roll20 _does_ have a DH character sheet developed by user Neirin D., and the new Character Vault feature would allow you to store characters for use in later campaigns.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my self properly. we are looking for a mobile app, offline and mobile support is most important. Not a web app. Android / iOS / mobile / tablet. We were thinking that it would be really good to be able to have all our characters in an app accessible from our phone.

Comment: @AlexandrosSpyropoulos You should edit your question and add that information.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be the best answer, this is only what I do. I think it's quite difficult for regular users, but I post here because it's handy to me.

- I have all characters sheets of all games (including DH) in a very simple HTML format that looks good on a text editor and on a browser.
- Those character sheets are stored on a git server I have hosted. I think there must be some git servers for free use that you can use for that purpose.
- I have git clients on my computer and my mobile devices that allow me to ubiquitously access to the last version.
- BONUS: I have a script on the git server that puts the uploaded sheets and all the changes online, so I can access them from any device that has a browser, even if it has no git client.

git is a version control program that, like all of its kind, allow to store documents in all its versions, storing all changes, and lets you access how the document was at any time.

A simpler approach, but still a technical one, would be to use one of the multiple clouds available for use. Those applications allow you to automatically synchronize the documents on all devices, but usually allow you to operate them offline. I recommend owncloud for freedom and privacy issues, but it may be difficult to find/create a server for a regular user.

None of these solutions are character generators, and hardly managers. I said this wasn't going to be the best answer. But they're the solutions I use for the problems you posted.

Comment: Nice solution. I may have to implement something similar myself!

Answer (score 0):

Apps for W40k doesn't exist due to licensing issues with Gamers Workshop, but I do something really simple: 
I download the xls from this site http://www.blackmoor.org.uk/40K.html
Which is a really good character generator and I print it to PDF and keep it on my phone. I take separate notes which I later add to the xls and print again.

I know it's a hassle to make all the changes, but for the moment that is the only option I have found to have everything needed for Dark Heresy games.

Hope this helps!